# Unable to get the members list from local administrator group through powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am unable to get the list of members from local administrator group after running the following command. its showing the error " missing closing '}' every time. Please help me on it or if have another scripts then please share with me.

```
function get-localusers { 
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,valuefrompipeline=$true)]
        [string]$strComputer
    ) 
    begin {} 
    Process { 
        $adminlist =""
        $powerlist =""
        $computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer")
        $AdminGroup = $computer.psbase.children.find("Administrators")
        $powerGroup = $computer.psbase.children.find("Power Users")
        $powerGroup = $computer.psbase.children.find("Power Users")
        $Adminmembers= $AdminGroup.psbase.invoke("Members") | % {
            $.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $, $null)
        } 
        $Powermembers= $PowerGroup.psbase.invoke("Members") | % {
            $.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $, $null)
        } 
        foreach ($admin in $Adminmembers) { 
            $adminlist = $adminlist + $admin + "," 
        } 
        foreach ($poweruser in $Powermembers) { 
            $powerlist = $powerlist + $poweruser + "," 
        } 
        $Computer = New-Object psobject $computer | Add-Member noteproperty ComputerName $strComputer $computer | Add-Member noteproperty Administrators $adminlist $computer | Add-Member noteproperty PowerUsers $powerlist
        Write-Output $computer

    } 
    end {} 
}

Get-Content C:\temp\server_list.txt | get-localusers | Export-Csv C:\temp\localusers.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you what to reference to the object in a Foreach-Object (%) block you have to use `$_`

Change the Foreach-Object part in your code to this:

```
$Adminmembers= $AdminGroup.psbase.invoke("Members") | % {
    $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
} 
$Powermembers= $PowerGroup.psbase.invoke("Members") | % {
    $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
}
```